# How do you loop through an unknown amount of children and children of children in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to loop through html that looks like this...

```
    <div>
        <span>
            ...
        </span>
        <span>
            ...
        </span>
        <span>
            ...
        </span>
        <span>
            ...
        </span>
        <div>
            <header>
                ...
            </header>
            <div>
                ...
            </div>
            <div>
                ...
            </div>
            ...
        </div>
        <div>
            <header>
                ...
            </header>
            <div>
                ...
            </div>
            <div>
                ...
            </div>
            ...
        </div>
        <div>
            <header>
                ...
            </header>
            <div>
                ...
            </div>
            <div>
                ...
            </div>
            ...
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
```

I need to get data that's inside each of the divs of the div children, ignoring all of the header elements and span elements. There are an unknown amount of div children elements and also an unknown number of divs within each div child. Is there a way I can loop through this, I've been trying things for an hour now, and I'm not any closer to doing it.

This is what I've tried doing, I'm using selenium.

```
let i = 4
while(driver.findElement(By.xpath(`//*[@id="football"]/div/div/div/div[${i}]`))){
    let j = 1
    while(driver.findElement(By.xpath(`//*[@id="football"]/div/div/div/div[${i}]/div/div/div[${j}]`))){
        console.log(i, j)
        j++
    }
    i++
}
```

This just logs 4, 1 and then 4, 2 and then 4,3 and so on...

Comment: Probably using a recursive function. What have you tried so far? May you share a [mre] of that?

Comment: What's the actual problem? For every element check if there are any `.children`. If so iterate over them and check the `.nodeName`, or `.querySelectorAll()`, or ...

Comment: What is the "data" that's inside these elements? Are you just trying to retrieve strings or entire elements?

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve entire elements

Comment: What if a div contains a header? Do you return that div with the header inside it? Or do you only want the elements at the bottom of the ancestor tree?

Comment: I just need the div elements at the bottom of this tree

Answer (score 0):

This is a very simple and naive example of a recursive "algorithm" to get all the descendants of a given DOM node.

```js
const findAllChildren = (root) =>
  root.children.length > 0
    ? [root, [...root.children].flatMap(findAllChildren)].flat()
    : root;

console.log(
  findAllChildren(document.body)
);
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<div>Hello
  <div>World</div>
</div>
<div>Hello
  <div>World
    <div>Hello
      <div>World</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I hope you can use this to make your own, better, implementation.

---

If you only want the div elements at the bottom (`[<div>World</div>, <div>World</div>]` from the above example) you can do the following:

```js
const findAllChildren = (root) =>
  root.children.length > 0
    ? [...root.children].flatMap(findAllChildren)
    : root;

console.log(
  [...document.querySelectorAll('body > div')].flatMap(findAllChildren)
);
```

```html
<p>Hello</p>
<div>Hello
  <div>World</div>
</div>
<div>Hello
  <div>World
    <div>Hello
      <div>World</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @PeterSeliger apologies. This approach was only meant to demonstrate a naive recursive function that the OP can then edit to adjust to their requirements.

Comment: you are right. I missed this point of yours because I just focused on the code and not on the provided text.

Comment: @PeterSeliger no problem. I'm going to add another example, hopefully closer to what the OP want's, but that'll take a bit longer -- I still don't really understand what the OP wants